# hudi-flink-bundle unable to load the s3-fs-hadoop plugin

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-sql, apache-hudi

When using the `hudi-flink-bundle.jar`, our Flink SQL jobs are unable to load the `s3-fs-hadoop` plugin.

### Details

We are using Flink 1.17 with Hudi 0.13.1 on top of S3. Following the Hudi [documentation](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/next/flink-quick-start-guide/), we created our own Flink Docker image and added the `hudi-flink-bundle.jar` to the `flink/lib` directory. We also created a plugin folder for the `s3-fs-hadoop` plugin and copied the plugin jar from the `flink/opt` directory.

The Flink job jars do not contain the `hudi-flink-bundle` or the `s3-fs-hadoop` libraries. When running Flink jobs, we get this exception:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found`

If we copy the `s3-fs-hadoop` plugin jar to the `flink/lib` folder then everything works, but the plugin jar contains a lot of libraries that conflict with versions we are using in our job jar.

I've read the Flink [debugging classloading](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/ops/debugging/debugging_classloading/) docs, but it doesn't explain how or if plugin jar dependencies can be loaded in the application classloader.